# Missing environment variables of connections

Tags: airflow

I added connection to s3 from UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2cfN.png)

and supposed to see `AIRFLOR_CONN_S3_CONN` in my env variables due to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html, but it didn't show up
(I used `BashOperator` with `printenv` command to see all env variables but didn't find any `AIRFLOR_CONN_`). What can be the problem?

I'm using Airflow 2.2.5

Comment: you can define connection using env variable with this convention (you wont see it in the UI). but if you define in the connections it won't be an env variable

Comment: Thanks! Solved it through parsing using BaseHook and pushing to XCOM.